# Error creating R package using RCPP package : Error in dyn.load in macOS

Tags: c++, ios, r, rcpp

I'm trying to create R package from cpp code using RCPP package but i found the error below.
I'm using macOS sierra, Rstudio, R on latest version.

I did steps as following....

1.using Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackage") but the Makevars or Makevars.win was not generated.

2.run compileAttributes to generates RcppExport.cpp

3.run sourceCpp(rcpp_script.cpp) and then error dyn.load as below.

```
Error in dyn.load("/private/var/folders/p4/hx950qdj5hb8zrvzc74_rpr40000gn/T/RtmpX9AU6m/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-0.12.11/sourcecpp_11cc996e86d/sourceCpp_93.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/p4/hx950qdj5hb8zrvzc74_rpr40000gn/T/RtmpX9AU6m/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-0.12.11/sourcecpp_11cc996e86d/sourceCpp_93.so':
  dlopen(/private/var/folders/p4/hx950qdj5hb8zrvzc74_rpr40000gn/T/RtmpX9AU6m/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-0.12.11/sourcecpp_11cc996e86d/sourceCpp_93.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN23stream_clustering_class3nanER11data_readerRK13config_reader
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/p4/hx950qdj5hb8zrvzc74_rpr40000gn/T/RtmpX9AU6m/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-0.12.11/sourcecpp_11cc996e86d/sourceCpp_93.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /private/var/folders/p4/hx950qdj5hb8zrvzc74_rpr40000gn/T/RtmpX9AU6m/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-0.12.11/sourcecpp_11cc996e86d/sourceCpp_93.so
```

After find out about this error and i've found many suggestions with Makevars file. Can i create this file by myself?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please see "How to create a minimally reproducible example".

Comment: I think we stopped added a `src/Makevars` when we changed Rcpp package builds to no longer require linking.  The reference to it in the help file is wrong and I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, even after editing, is a little hard to make sense of.

Your linking error indicates that you reference an external function you are *not* supplying in code or linking instructions. Such code is no longer the simplest possible use case for Rcpp, but rather more advanced.

But we have a entire vignette about this: [Rcpp-package](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf). Have a look at it, it should answer your questions.

For better questions on StackOverflow, please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).